# How to stop runner trying to find step definitions for scenarios marked as @Manual

Tags: java, gherkin, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

Example feature scenario is

```
  @JIRA_BOND_007
  @manual
  @manual-result:passed
  @manual-last-tested:sprint-1
  @manual-test-evidence:https://some.external/link.png
  Scenario: Dont want Manual steps to cause step definition failure
    Given John Ferguson Smart releases a new version of serenity bdd
    When tester marks a test as manual
    Then runner should not fail because of error "io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException:"
```

error example:

```
@When("tester marks a test as manual")
public tester_marks_a_test_as_manual(){
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
**io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException:**
```

I want these scenarios tagged @manual to show in serenity report but not cause the runner to throw error because its looking for step definitions that dont exist.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that we have now way around this as per comments from John Ferguson Smart:

"However, Cucumber does not allow steps to not have a step definition (they will result in a build failure). There isn't an easy work-around to this: "

So im afraid you will have to do

GIVEN
WHEN
THEN

or

1. Given
2. When
3. Then

Comment: This was published as an answer, but does not attempt to answer the question. Possibly it should be a comment, otherwise please edit your answer and add an explanation that may be useful.